# Android app work slowly

Tags: android

I am using Navigation drawer for my app.
For each fragments I have a big image(I can't use a specify image for each size, because I have more than 100 3d Image for this reason I decide put a large and prefect image in drawable folder and for each size use of those).
I have a trouble, when I run app on the tablets it's work perfectly but when run it on the phones it's slow, I guess it's for images.
Anybody can help me, how can I improve my app?
Note:I know It's not good way, one of the best way is I download image from internet or something like that way. Unfortunately I should make that app as offline.

Comment: Use smaller images for phones. Of course, using a single image is not the proper way. You must use multiple copies of the same. Please refer to the official docs about supporting multiple screens. There is no `prefect image` which will fit on every screen resolution.

Comment: @Rotwang I can't use images for each sizes. My app size is 100mg, if I  put another images for another size my app size will 150mg. I don't wanna increase my app size.

Comment: Well, then have it run slowly. A 100 MB app is an overkill anyway. It seems the result of a poor design. Either in the UI elements or in code.

Comment: Why would you use "large" images and expect the app to be not slow? Or or even small, like you say less than 150MB?

Comment: @Rotwang It's not my idea, customer wants offline app with highest quality.

Comment: @spikespaz because I wanna one image for each size, small, normal, large and xlarge for this reason I decide put large image for support tablets and also use for phones.

Comment: `for this reason I decide put large image for support tablets and also use for phones.` Not a good idea.

Comment: Your customers want the moon? Then they should not complain that it takes a lot of space.

Comment: @Rotwang I agree with you. I wanna put image on server and get those by json, but he wanna this app should be offline. he doesn't want online app. I don't have any choice.

Comment: Your only choice, my dear, is to take the common route: provide multiple images. Also be aware that PNGs can be compressed with no apparent quality loss, with utilities such as *optipng*.

Comment: @Rotwang I guess JPGs can compressed images. I use JPGs images on the app.

Comment: `I guess JPGs can compressed images` I guess you told me you wanted **quality**. JPGs are **not** a high-quality format, because of their **lossy** compression algorithm.

Comment: yes as I said I want high quality but as you know If I save each image by png format maybe my app has more than 200mg. for this reason I decide set background to image(color with app background color). all of the image exported from 3DMax.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because your Bitmap is huge. Instead of putting the images directly on ImageView, consider using BitmapFactory.Options to resize image before loading it. Other option would be using a library like Picasso for loading image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I try to implement this option.